# replacing part of a hyperlink in excel using vbscript

Tags: excel, vba

I have a row with hundreds of hyperlinks pointing to a path that was changed a bit. can someone help me with creating a vbscript in excel. I have some code I found but it is not working very good. There are a few conditions I have to take in consideration that some of the links are correct and no need to edit and some I just need to edit a little bit. Here is an example of three rows.

```
\\US.MyCompany.net\Main_Folder\DATA\Sub_folder\a\file1.pdf
\\US.MyCompany.net\Main_Folder\DATA\Sub_folder\b\file1.pdf
\\US.MyCompany.net\Main_Folder\DATA\Sub_folder\c\file1.pdf
```

I basically need to edit the current path and add a folder named NewFolder right after the DATA so it would look like the following.

```
\\US.MyCompany.net\Main_Folder\DATA\NewFolder\Sub_folder\a\file1.pdf
\\US.MyCompany.net\Main_Folder\DATA\NewFolder\Sub_folder\b\file1.pdf
\\US.MyCompany.net\Main_Folder\DATA\NewFolder\Sub_folder\c\file1.pdf
```

The code I got so far works but only to the exact search meaning it will add Newfolder even if it exist it will not skip it.

### When I run the code bellow a few times it will keep on adding the Newfolder even if it exist.

```
Sub ReplaceHyperlinkAdresses()
Dim hypLink As Hyperlink
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
For Each hypLink In ws.Hyperlinks
If hypLink.Address Like "\\US.MyCompany.net\Main_Folder\DATA*" Then
hypLink.Address =Replace
(hypLink.Address, "\\US.MyCompany.net\Main_Folder\DATA",
"\\US.MyCompany.net\Main_Folder\DATA\NewFolder")
End If
Next hypLink
Next ws
End Sub
```

---

Comment: [tag:excel-vba] or [tag:vbscript] ? Please make up your mind. They are **not** the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ReplaceHyperlinkAdresses()
Dim hypLink As Hyperlink
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    For Each hypLink In ws.Hyperlinks
        If hypLink.Address Like "\\US.MyCompany.net\Main_Folder\DATA*" AND _
           Not hypLink.Address Like "\\US.MyCompany.net\Main_Folder\DATA\NewFolder*"Then
            hypLink.Address =Replace(hypLink.Address, _
                             "\\US.MyCompany.net\Main_Folder\DATA", _
                             "\\US.MyCompany.net\Main_Folder\DATA\NewFolder")
        End If
    Next hypLink
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a runtime error 7  out of memory. I guess it is because of the number of rows

Comment: Is this the only code you're running?  How many rows of data?

Comment: 14892 rows in total